# What causes sprite tearing / corruption in unity PC stand alone running on Windows XP?

Tags: unity, sprites

The image below is representative of my client's experience running the released version of an app I created for him on his Windows XP Machine.

I built it using Unity 4.5.  The messed up buttons are the product of a png import to a sprite render all done using the Unity editor.  I created the sprites at a resolution of 1024X96 and scaled them down using the editor.  I have the applications default resolution set up for 800X600 windowed and the user can resize the game window.

I cannot seem to recreate the problem using the editor or a release on my local machine.  He said it worked fine on his Windows 7 Machine, though he said the text looked blurry.  Any thoughts?

[image: Screen Tearing Example]

Comment: That looks more like corruption than "tearing" which could be due to a driver or even physical hardware problems.  Updating drivers might fix the problem.

Comment: @MooseBoys, corruption does sound better than "tearing" - I couldn't think of a better way of describing it.  Let me talk to my client about updating the drivers.  THANKS, for the feedback!

Comment: I am going to try to scale the images so that they are less than 800 PX wide and release again.  I figure there might be some logic error occurring involving the aspect ratio that the XP machine is running on.  It is odd that these graphics are the only ones that are corrupted...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that scaling the images for the buttons from 1024X96 to 798X75 while targeting a default resolution of 800X600 solved the graphics corruption.  I wish I knew why this was the case, but I will take a win any day.  Thanks to all who have contributed.